# Editing sounds in Alexa Skill - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I'm programming in Python an Amazon Alexa skill for mixing different sounds saved in S3 Bucket.

What is the best way to do it (edit sounds) inside a Alexa Skill?
Is useful implement a AWS Lambda?

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried ? either approach you mentioned should work, since both are essentially just lambda functions anyway

Comment: I have tried with PyDub but with mp3 files it require ffmpeg. The issue is that ffmpeg does not install correctly in Alexa Developer Console and the code give me errors while if I run the code on my computer, it edit sounds succesfully